# Tensorflow not working after I update it in Jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow

I updated my tensorflow in jupyter becuase I had some trouble using transfer learning, I used to following line to update the library:
`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

Then, when I tried to run import tensorflow, this error appear:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 5
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow import keras
      8 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:38
     35 import sys as _sys
     36 import typing as _typing
---> 38 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     39 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     41 # Make sure code inside the TensorFlow codebase can use tf2.enabled() at import.

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py:37
     29 # We aim to keep this file minimal and ideally remove completely.
     30 # If you are adding a new file with @tf_export decorators,
     31 # import it in modules_with_exports.py instead.
     32 
     33 # go/tf-wildcard-import
     34 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     36 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
---> 37 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     39 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     40 
     41 # Bring in subpackages.
     42 from tensorflow.python import data

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py:30
     27 import six
     29 from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2
---> 30 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     31 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import coordination_config_pb2
     32 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config_pb2.py:20
     18 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import debug_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_protobuf_dot_debug__pb2
     19 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_protobuf_dot_rewriter__config__pb2
---> 20 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rpc_options_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_protobuf_dot_rpc__options__pb2
     21 try:
     22   tensorflow_dot_tsl_dot_protobuf_dot_rpc__options__pb2 = tensorflow_dot_core_dot_protobuf_dot_rpc__options__pb2.tensorflow_dot_tsl_dot_protobuf_dot_rpc__options__pb2

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rpc_options_pb2.py:14
      9 # @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)
     11 _sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()
---> 14 from tensorflow.tsl.protobuf import rpc_options_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_tsl_dot_protobuf_dot_rpc__options__pb2
     16 from tensorflow.tsl.protobuf.rpc_options_pb2 import *
     18 DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor_pool.Default().AddSerializedFile(b'\n*tensorflow/core/protobuf/rpc_options.proto\x12\x10tensorflow.dummy\x1a)tensorflow/tsl/protobuf/rpc_options.protoBWZUgithub.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/protobuf/for_core_protos_go_protoP\x00\x62\x06proto3')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tsl'
```

I have no idea how to handle this error.

I tried to update jupyter, I also tried to uninstall tensorflow but I couldn't do it since the pip uninstall took ages to run.